# WCF DataService Loading Data Issue

Tags: c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I am working on C#.Net 4.0. I created WCF Dataservice and i have a client layer. 
i have two tables and its been joined through SQL Server 2008 "View",. while i seeing in the SQl 2008 management studio or from the Web browser i was able to see the right output. 
But when i connected from the client(through Proxy generation and context), 
its giving the different value than which is coming from browser or Database "View". 
So what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems its SQL Management Studio bug, the query was wrong and it supposed to give zero records, but i was able to see some records in the SQL Management Studio. So nothing wrong with WCF DataService, its all from SQL Management Studio.